# React Webview, Intercepting unknown url type

Tags: reactjs, electron

I have an app, written in react hosted in electron.

There's a webview which loads an external website within the view.

The user logs into the external website to complete the oauth handshake (which all works fine), however, one particular app has a 302 redirect to a urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob?code= url containing the auth code.  (Out of band token delivery)

I need to intercept this and prevent the webview trying to continue the navigation; I've tried using did-start-navigation but this doesn't seem to get fired and this is apparently the only cancellable event. did-redirect-navigation does fire and let me get the url to slurp the token however, but, obviously is no good as the os fires an "unknown url" dialog.

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

(Apologies react newbie here!)

Comment: `session.defaultSession.webRequest` can have listeners attached to it and may help you. For example I know there's a `session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived`.